# $f=x^4+1$ is reducible over infinite field $F$ with characteristic $p>0$

Tags: field-theory, extension-field

My approach:

For $p=2$, we have $(x+1)^4=x^4+1$ so reducible, let's assume $p>2$.

Suppose $F$ is finite, if $|F|=p^r$ with $r\geq2$, then we can find an element $a\in F$ such that $a^4=-1$; if $|F|=p^r$ with $r=1$, let $a$ be the root of $f$, by contradiction we have $[F_{p^2}:F(a)][F(a):F]=2$ ($F_{p^2}$ an extension field of $F$ with order $p^2$) and $[F(a):F]=4$ which is impossible.

Suppose $F$ is infinite. if the below statement is true then the result follows from finite case

> For any infinite field $F$ with characteristic $p>0$, it contains finite subfields with order $p^r$ for all $r>0$

I have read a post somewhere that the above statement is true for $r=1$, but I don't know if it is still true for other $r$.

Comment: Your highlighted conjecture is wrong. Consider the function field $\Bbb F_p(t)$; the only finite subfield it contains is the prime field $\Bbb F_p$. Fortunately, that is enough, as the answer shows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $\sqrt{-1} \in F$ then $x^4+1 = \left(x^2+\sqrt{-1}\right)\left(x^2-\sqrt{-1}\right)$.

If $\sqrt{2} \in F$ then $x^4+1 = \left(x^2+\sqrt{2}x+1\right)\left(x^2-\sqrt{2}x+1\right)$.

If $\sqrt{-2} \in F$ then $x^4+1 = \left(x^2+\sqrt{-2}x-1\right)\left(x^2-\sqrt{-2}x-1\right)$.

Since $\text{char }F = p$, we have the subfield $\mathbb{F}_p$ generated by $1$.

If $-1$ is a square mod $p$ we are done since $\sqrt{-1} \in \mathbb{F}_p \subseteq F$.

Otherwise, $\left(\frac{-2}{p}\right) = \left(\frac{-1}{p}\right)\left(\frac{2}{p}\right) = -\left(\frac{2}{p}\right)$, so if $p$ is odd then either $2$ or $-2$ is a square mod $p$.

If $p = 2$ then $-1$ is a square mod $p$ so in all cases we are done and $x^4+1$ is reducible in $F$ (in fact, over the subfield $\mathbb{F}_p$).

Comment: What do you mean by the notation $(\frac{2}{p})$ ?

Comment: @Tob_Ernack I m trying to tag you.

Comment: @NotaChoice The $\left(\frac{p}{q}\right)$ is a standard notation for the [Legendre symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_symbol)

Comment: Can you please explain the reasoning in more detail? For someone with no exposure to number theory.

Comment: @NotaChoice The three factorizations show that if $-1$, $2$ or $-2$ has a square root in $F$ then the polynomial is reducible over $F$. Since $F$ has characteristic $p$, the finite field $\mathbb{F}_p$ is a subfield of $F$, so it is enough to show that either $-1$, $2$ or $-2$ have square roots modulo $p$. The rest of the argument uses properties of Legendre symbols to show this holds.

Comment: @NotaChoice If either $-1$ or $-2$ is a square mod $p$ we are done. So we want to show that if $-1$ and $-2$ are not squares mod $p$ then $2$ *must* be a square mod $p$. Indeed, if $2$ were not a square mod $p$, then $-2 = (-1)\cdot 2$ would be a product of non-squares mod $p$. But the product of two non-squares is a square, so this is impossible. The Legendre symbol encodes this sort of argument in the notation $\left(\frac{p}{q}\right)$.